# What are the major differences between Web API and ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The title really sums up my question.  I have used both technologies but I am uncertain as to what one offers that is substantially different than the other.  In essence:

What criteria and/or guidance should one consider when selecting ASP MVC or Web API when designing a restful web application?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Purpose**

ASP.NET MVC is focused on making output of HTML easy. ASP.NET Web API is focused on making output of raw data easy.

In the WebForms world, ASP.NET MVC would be equivalent to .aspx pages and ASP.NET Web API would be .asmx.

**Although nothing is impossible**

While it's possible to make Web API output HTML and MVC output raw data, you will need additional work. For example, making additional classes to handle text/html during content negotiation in Web API, or adding logic to handle OData queries in MVC.

**Assumptions**

The default assumption for both MVC and Web API are different too. MVC by default assumes user submitted data can come from multiple sources, be it in the query string or in the form.

Web API by default assumes that primitive type comes from query string and non-primitive types comes from the form. It also assumes that you would only want to read the form body once, without caching, to have lower memory usage and better performance.

Going against the defaults requires additional work, that to me, does not make sense at all.

EDIT:

Also, GET AJAX request is blocked by MVC's JsonResult by default to prevent CSRF, while Web API allows GET AJAX request by default.

**Update for MVC 6**

MVC 6 unifies MVC and Web API and allows you to return ViewResult like in MVC or object like in Web API, and the framework will take care of content negotiation, creating the HTML, JSON or XML for you. Lower memory usage also arrives in MVC, by using its custom pipeline instead of what is provided by System.Web.

So going forward, there's no distinction between the MVC and Web API.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that the main difference between the two is ASP MVC is designed to output HTML, and Web API is designed to output everything else.  Is this the only factor that one should consider?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I'll use MVC for my website, while Web API to provide the data that my mobile app needs. Both of them can reside in the same project.

Comment: @JeowLiHuan  It's quite easy to strip away the in-the-box defaults from Web Api and use your own set of defaults.  In that way it can become the foundation for your own opinionated web api framework.